# select top 1 with max 2 fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table :

```
+------+-------+------------------------------------+
| id   | rev   | class                              |
+------+-------+------------------------------------+
| 1    | 10    | 2                                  |
| 1    | 10    | 5                                  |

| 2    | 40    | 6                                  |
| 2    | 50    | 6                                  |
| 2    | 52    | 1                                  |

| 3    | 33    | 3                                  |
| 3    | 63    | 5                                  |
+------+-------+------------------------------------+
```

I only need the rows where rev AND then class columns have max value.

```
+------+-------+------------------------------------+
| id   | rev   | class                              |
+------+-------+------------------------------------+
| 1    | 10    | 5                                  |
| 2    | 52    | 1                                  |
| 3    | 63    | 5                                  |
+------+-------+------------------------------------+
```

Query cost is important for me.

Comment: can you make this more readable ? and add a question or what is the problem you have? also what have you tried ....

Comment: Try to create a sql fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: What database are you using?  And why do people design tables so a column called `id` have duplicated values?

Comment: I'm using sql server 2012, id is sample integer field and is not unique and primary key. you assume other name like X.

Comment: If you only need "rows where rev AND then class columns have max value." then why are you including the second row in your example?

Answer (score 1):

Just the rows that satisfy the condition that it has both max values?

Here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6b1f/4);

```
SELECT  h.id, h.rev, h.class
FROM (  SELECT  id, 
                MAX( rev ) rev, 
                MAX( class ) class
        FROM    Herp
        GROUP BY id ) derp
INNER JOIN Herp h
    ON  h.rev = derp.rev
    AND h.class = derp.class;
```

Comment: What does the `inner join` add? I think it is already good without it.

Comment: Not if there's no record where a specific `id` has both `MAX` values;  Consider adding a row such as ( 3, 64, 4 ).

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way might be to have an index on `t(id, rev)` and `t(id, class)` and then do:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.rev > t.rev
                 ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.class > t.class
                 );
```

SQL Server is pretty smart in terms of optimization, so the aggregation approach might be just as good.  However, in terms of performance, this is just a bunch of index lookups.

Comment: [Can I inline links?](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/829b4/1) If so, I think you're correct - it would be have to be in the context of a specific case to determine which of these forms performed better overall, with actual table usage in mind ( reads / inserts / etc ).

Comment: My table total rows is over 50 million records.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a SQL 2012 example.  Very straight forward with the implied table and the PARTITION function.

Basically, with each ID as a partition/group, sort the values of the other fields in a descending order assigning each one an incrementing RowId, then only take the first one.

```
select id, rev, [class]
from
    (
        SELECT id, rev, [class], 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rev DESC, [class] desc) AS RowId
        FROM sample
    ) t
where RowId = 1
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5476/1/0)

*Keep in mind, this works with the criteria in the example dataset, and not the MAX of two fields as stated in the question's title.*

Comment: Thanks, but i've tested this solutions and it was very slow. i have a huge table with 50 million rows and I need less then 30 seconds query execution time.

Comment: Then add a covering index over the three fields in the correct order -- id, rev desc, and class desc.

Comment: join solution is Dramatically faster than window function.

Comment: The Join solution returns a different result set. It depends on what you actually want. Seems to be nested maximum: find the maximum rev and for this rev find the maximum class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean: the max of `rev` and the max of `class`. If not, please clarify what to do when there is no row where both fields have the highest value.

```
select id
,      max(rev)
,      max(class)
from   table
group
by     id
```

If you mean total value of `rev` and `class` use this:

```
select id
,      max
,      rev
from   table
where  id in
       (  select id
          ,      max(rev + class)
          from   table
          group
          by     id
       )
```